# HTML5 Drag and Drop dataTransfer and Chrome

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

The following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
console.log(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

with Firefox get correctly the `dataTransfer` object and returns the image's id (`drag1`) when the `allowDrop` function called by `ondragover` event is executed, but in Chrome `getData` returns an empty string.
Is it a bug or Chrome returns a valid `dataTransfer` object only with the `ondrop` event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 DnD dataTransfer setData or getData not working in every browser except Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927309/html5-dnd-datatransfer-setdata-or-getdata-not-working-in-every-browser-except-fi)

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow datatransfer this way due to security reasons. I had the same issue and I used different procedure to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Chrome doesn't set the dataTransfer before drop.
I just set my drag reference in a "global" variable instead. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use **dataTransfer** in chrome except in the **drop** event .

you should declare a **Global** variable instead .

for your situation try this :

```
function drag(ev)
{
   el = ev.target;
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
function allowDrop(ev)
{
   console.log(el);
   ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's very trick in Chrome. I have a simple page to drag some div into some container. I set the dragging div element id into **dataTransfer** at **ondragstart** method. I try to get the dragging div from **dataTransfer** in **ondrop** callback, and then copy it to the container. Everything works very well in Chrome on local(I mean just open it from explorer, **file://**). But when I deploy it to web site, and then open it via **http://**. It does not work in chrome. So I use the same solution with Per Digre. Set the global variable on **dragstart**, clean the variable on **dragend**. Hope it help you!

Comment: So strange. I am seeing this as well. Locally Chrome works just like Firefox with drag-and-drop, but as soon as I try it from a web server reading from dataTransfer during `ondragenter` etc. stops working. Frustrating!