# Why my javascript does not work properly on a github page?

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

My JavaScript does not work properly on a GitHub page: The drag and drop feature is broken on the GitHub page, but not when running locally with the same browser. 
I tried with both chrome and Firefox (up to date version)

[1- Here is the GitHub page not working properly](http://arnooo.github.io/sosimplist/#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)

[2- And here is the source code which is working locally on my computer](https://github.com/Arnooo/sosimplist/tree/gh-pages)

I put a breakpoint in lib/list.js:84, on the `dragenter` event. We should go through the next block. `event.dataTransfer.getData('source')` does not return the value we set before.

Here is a part of the source code: (the rest on GitHub)

```
         self_.itemContainer_.addEventListener(
             'dragstart',
             function(event) {
                if(event.target.classList.contains('sosimplist-item')){
                    var parentToDrag = event.target.closest('.sosimplist-item');
                    parentToDrag.style.zIndex = 1;
                    parentToDrag.style.boxShadow = '3px 3px 3px grey';
                    event.dataTransfer.setData('elementId', parentToDrag.id);
                    event.dataTransfer.setData('source', 'item');
                }else{}
             },
             false
         );
         self_.itemContainer_.addEventListener(
             'dragenter',
             function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                if(event.dataTransfer.getData('source') === 'item'){
                    var elementDragged = document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData('elementId'));
                    if(elementDragged){
                        var parentTarget = event.target.closest('.sosimplist-item');
                        var isContainInThisList = parentTarget.parentNode.contains(elementDragged);
                        if(isContainInThisList){
                            elementDragged.nextSibling === parentTarget ?
                            elementDragged.parentNode.insertBefore(elementDragged, parentTarget.nextSibling) :
                            elementDragged.parentNode.insertBefore(elementDragged, parentTarget);
                        }else{}
                    }else{}
                }else{}
             },
             false
         );
```

Comment: What have you done to debug your code?

Comment: It seems like  'event.dataTransfer.getData('source')' is not working when running from github page. I put a breakpoint here: lib/list.js:84, when you drag an item, you should go through this block

Comment: *same brother* = *same browser* ?

Comment: Please post your code here, not just as a link to github

Comment: Your gh pages version is working on ubuntu 14.04 Firefox 43 but not on Chromium 47.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering myself, I have fixed this issue by not accessing `event.dataTransfer.getData` in the `dragenter` event. I am using a local object to store information I need instead.

This thread inspired me:

[HTML5 DnD dataTransfer setData or getData not working in every browser except Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927309/html5-dnd-datatransfer-setdata-or-getdata-not-working-in-every-browser-except-fi)

Thank you for your help