# Disable the drag-and-drop for text

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am developing a drag-and-drop system for image files and I have noticed that the `dragenter` event is also executed on the selected text drag.

```
$(document).on("dragenter", "#element", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // Check if we are dragging text

    if(is_text){ // <- HERE
        console.log("dragging text!");
    }else{
        console.log("dragging file!");
    }
});
```

I want to detect that the dragged object is not text, so the previous `console.log` would not run if it were.

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION:**

```
var dragging_text = false;

$(window).on("dragstart", function(event){
    dragging_text = true;
    console.log("dragstart");
});

$(document).on("dragenter", "#element", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if(dragging_text){
        console.log("NO, dragging text!");
    }else{
        console.log("OK, dragging file!");
    }
});
```

Comment: just not understand what you mean by text, you can not drag and drop text !

Comment: @mooga The `dragenter` event fires when you select and drag text. I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you know:

```
 var dragging_text = false;

$(window).on("dragstart", function(event){
    dragging_text = true;
    console.log("dragstart");
});

$(document).on("dragenter", "#element", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if(dragging_text){
        console.log("NO, dragging text!");
    }else{
        console.log("OK, dragging file!");
    }
    dragging_text = false;
});
```

Comment: I've researched about `dragstart` and it seems to work fine. I update the post with my solution.

Comment: Don't forget to add 'dragging_text = false;' in the dragenter() event, tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include `dragging_text = false;` in `dragenter` event. I've done tests and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer)

```
$(document).on("dragenter", "#element", function(event){   
    if(event.dataTransfer.files.length > 0){ // <- HERE
        console.log("dragenter");
    }else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have updated the question to see if it is better understood now.

Comment: have used `if(event.dataTransfer.files.length > 0){` ?

Comment: Yes, but with that line it does not let me drag files.

Comment: because you block it anyway, i have changed the code , try it

Comment: `dataTransfer` works in the `dragenter` event? I have documented and I have seen that it does not work.

Comment: I think the problem is that

Comment: @Smark what exactly you mean by text drag and drop ? can you add an example

Comment: When you select text with the cursor, you click on it and drag it over `#element`. I want to avoid that the `dragenter` event is executed in these cases.

Comment: @Smark you can't avoid it's execution but you can block it

Comment: And how can I detect that the object I am dragging is text or a file?

Comment: by using that `if(event.dataTransfer.files.length > 0)` , check the my answer again

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not work for me. Check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771177/detect-file-type-on-dragenter-cross-browser-solution and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762635/getting-the-filename-during-the-dragenter-event